# Game Maker bounce code not woking

Tags: game-maker

Okay so I am making one of those scrolling shooter Galaga-type game using Game Maker Studio. I created the first enemy and set up a spawner for them. They are supposed to just fly downwards towards your ship. That worked fine. But when I made the 2nd enemy, I wanted to make it move more slowly and side-to-side. I also wanted to make them bounce off the edges of the screen. But it just won't work. I can't figure what the hell the problem is and it it driving me insane. If anyone has any ideas, please, share them with me. If you need any more info on the game i can provide it. Here is the code for the step event of the 2nd enemy:

```
    // Control the enemy 
if (y > room_height+16) 
{
    instance_destroy();
}

// Die code
if (armor <= 0)
{
    instance_create(x, y, o_explosion_center);
    instance_destroy();
}

// Bounce off edges
if (x >= room_width-16) 
{
    hspeed = -1;
}

if (x < 16) 
{
    hspeed = 1;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code for the create event?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't say what wasn't working. The code you posted is correct, everything depends on the expected result.

One issue I can see id if this code is used by the two enemies. You want them to have different speeds, but once they bounce, their horizontal speeds will be 1 because you set hspeed to 1 and -1. When you create them, you should set a move_speed variable, and for the bouncing, write in the step event :

```
hspeed = -1*move_speed   //instead of hspeed = -1
```

and

```
hspeed = move_speed   //instead of hspeed = 1
```

This way, they will keep their initial speeds.

> For more help, could you please explain what doesn't work and post the creation code ?